# Scheme IDE for Windows

Tags: ide, scheme

What is a good Scheme IDE for Windows? OK, I'll admit it; I'm not at RMS's level, and don't want to use Emacs or any character-based interface -- I want a graphic IDE with colorization, a REPL, and usable, in-line help for a specific, well-documented dialect of Scheme. I have searched around and PLT Scheme/DrScheme seems the best, but even that does not look too sophisticated.

Comment: I agree with you that there is a lack of a VS-style IDE for Scheme.

Comment: It may be best to just go with Clojure, a Scheme-like language with more modern tool support.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[DrScheme](http://racket-lang.org/) is the best Scheme IDE I have found.  It has a JIT compiler, can build stand-alone executables or run in the traditional Scheme [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), has smart syntax editing  , as well as other traditional IDE features like Menu bars to change features.  Running/stopping your program is as easy as clicking 'Run'/'Stop'.  It also includes a macro-expander (if you're writing macros) as well as a debugger. It's Help menu includes both DrScheme-specific documentation, as well as various Scheme specifications (e.g., R5RS and R6RS).

If there is something you want in a Scheme IDE that is not in DrScheme already, I'm sure the  developers would be interested in hearing from you.

Comment: Is this suitable for use with SICP?

Answer (score 9):

I think you are done already. [DrScheme](http://plt-scheme.org/) is the most popular Scheme IDE.

Scheme is a bit of niche language, so do not be surprised not to find the kind of super-slick IDE support that is expected by Java/VisualBasic [WIMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIMP_(computing)) addicts.

Patronizing? Well, yes.

Comment: DrScheme is now known as DrRacket: https://racket-lang.org

Answer (score 7):

[PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org/) is an excellenet product well worth taking a look at. It's got all the features you're asking for

Comment: PLT-Scheme is now known as DrRacket: https://racket-lang.org

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want actually is Emacs. Let's see:

- *I want a graphic IDE*, the latest versions of Emacs are built on top of gtk.
- *with colorization*, it's **M-x font-lock-mode**
- *a REPL*, lookup [Quack mode](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/) for Emacs,
- *and usable, in-line help for a specific, well-documented dialect of Scheme*, that too, it's built into Quack.

Comment: I think Windows users will hardly love Emacs, it's too unfamiliar.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing with Xacc.Ide and Iron Scheme and found they were pretty good although they felt not finished in some places. They're good enough for trying out scheme, I'm not sure if I'd use them for writing commercial software though. I've seen the author of both of them hang around here so maybe he can tell more..

Comment: Hopefully I can make the VS support better during december/january. I have tons of ideas, just not sure how to wire them all up! Either way, both xacc.ide and the VS plugin is very R6RS-centric, and I would suggest DrScheme for anything else (I even use that for debugging sometimes).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know (I used DrScheme for a few months before switching to Emacs), DrScheme has many IDE-like features, but they are presented in a simplified interface because of its educational focus. Do some digging and I think you'll be happy what you find.

Also, I can't resist, since I *do* use Emacs---an OS specific install of emacs is hardly ever character based.

Comment: OK, I'll try that --  could you recommend  an "OS specific install of emacs"  -- do you mean this http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Getting-Emacs.html or some alternative GUIfied version?

Comment: Yes, a GUIfied version. I use Aquamacs (http://www.aquamacs.org) for Mac. It's been a while since I used Windows but I used a similar GUI  emacs there. On Linux I remember a GUI emacs being pre-installed, but I haven't used Linux much so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the scheme plugin for eclipse, I haven't try it yet.
It looks pretty nice.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/schemeway/the-schemescript-plugin/features/
and its git repository
https://github.com/schemeway/SchemeScript

Answer (score 1):

I personally use ChezScheme. 
I run scheme scripts from the console and edit them in eclipse, using the SchemeWay plugin. 
Eclipse is superior to Emacs, in my opinion, and it has some nice features, like automatic indentation and autocomplete for defined names.